# Does Apache NiFi support looping?

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there an option to perform processor operation in a loop on specific flowfile content?

As a specific example, when using `EvaluateXPath` I want to check the `Phone` element's value in each child using the following:

```
/Parent/Childrens/Child[i]/Phone[@Value='111']
```

Answer (score 2):

All relationships can be directed back to the processor they come from as long as that processor supports incoming connections.  For your example, you could provide the 'matched' relationship back to the same processor and have it again evaluate the path you were looking for.  This would continue on until that expression no longer evaluates to a match.

Answer (score 2):

Is your JSON structure recursive, or are you looking to iterate over the single "Child" array? If the latter, the SplitJson processor will create a new flow file for each element in your array, then you can use EvaluateJsonPath to get the value for "Phone" in each child, then RouteOnAttribute to filter on those whose value is 111:

[image]

This template (with a simple version of the JSON structure you gave) is available as a Gist ([here](https://gist.github.com/mattyb149/bd725cba2c34fb0f465f)). Note it needs NiFi 0.5.0+ for InvokeScriptedProcessor (which generates the sample JSON file)

Comment: Thanks mattyb! I learned a lot from your example (especially about templates & 'invokeScriptedProcessor')